# css blur filter on image with translate3d causing blurred edges

Tags: css-transforms, css-filters

I'm trying to achieve a blurred image effect with css and it works fine without `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` but the performance is horrible, so I need it included.  However with the transform, the edges of the container are giving me an unwanted blurred edge.  Is there a way to get around this?

I am using Chrome 37.  Seems to be fine in Safari 7.  Not supported in FF32.

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattybow/eq46b6v9/4/)